# Edit Text Values in CustomList

Tags: android-edittext, custom-lists, lost-focus

I am having EditText field in my customlist view. Value of editText is not persisted properly please help I am using holder class..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using to persist the data? Could it be possible the view is getting disassociated from the Activity and garbage collected?